# json find object by name and grab its value (api)

Tags: node.js, json, api, discord.js

i am grabbing the steam data and saving it to variable called body
now what i want to do is find `total_kills` its not necessary that this object is always at `body.playerstats.stats[0].value` so is there any way to find the body by `total_kills` and get its value 
the complete api reply is given below with beautified form

https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb2b563d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like body.playerstats.stats is an Array that contains objects. What you could do is go through that array and store all the objects that have `name: 'total_kills'`, something like this could work:

```js
const totalKillsArr = body.playerstats.stats.filter((stat) => {
    return stat.name === 'total_kills';
});
```

Once you have the new array of totalKills you can use reduce to get the sum of all total kills:

```js
const sumTotalKills = totalKills.reduce((sum, el) => {
    sum += el.value;
    return sum;
}, 0);
```

If there is only one object in the stats array that has the name of `total_kills` then just use a simple find function on the main array like this:

```js
const totalKills = body.playerstats.stats.find(stat => {
    return stat.name === 'total_kills';
});
```

This will find you the first object with name property of `total_kills`. If there is no such object it will return `undefined`.

Comment: thanks for the ans but is there a way to return value i tried `console.log(totalKills.value);` its returning me `undefined`

Comment: totalKills is a new array which contains objects that have the name property equal to 'total_kills'. If you also need to get a sum of all total_kills you loop through your new array and add the values to a variable.

Comment: Is there only one object with the name of `total_kills`? I misunderstood, in that case it is best to use a find function.

Comment: yes only one object with `total_kills` name and other are like `total_kills_ak47` like that